# For windows, a command-line bat file that displays total lines in each file in a directory

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, count

For windows, I need a command-line bat file that displays total lines in each file in a directory

I found similar questions but not this exact question.

Comment: An idea of what you want to do is not a question. What have you tried and with what results?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: This is for windows 10, although the question may be more general than that.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: example:  if a.txt has 7 lines, b.txt has 9 lines and c.txt has 11 lines, the output would be:  a.txt 7 b.txt 9 c.txt 11

Comment: Great. What do your code look like so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %%a in (*) do (
  <nul set /p=%%~na : 
  find /c /v "" <"%%~nxa"
)
```

Comment: This works very nicely.  I always add a 'pause' to the end of most bat-files [unless they're to be run in automated fashion!], but that's minor.

Comment: PowerShell is far more readable; example: `Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name,@{Name="Lines"; Expression={(Get-Content $_).Count}}`